# How to use Silex 2.x and Swiftmailer?

Tags: silex, swiftmailer

I'm trying to use Swiftmailer in Silex.
Added Swiftmailer:

```
composer require swiftmailer/swiftmailer

// Swiftmailer
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SwiftmailerServiceProvider());

// $app['swiftmailer.use_spool'] = false;

$app['swiftmailer.options'] = [
    'host'       => 'localhost',
    'port'       => '25',
    'username'   => '',
    'password'   => '',
    'encryption' => null,
    'auth_mode'  => null
];
```

Here is part of my route:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('[YourSite] Feedback')
    ->setFrom(['noreply@yoursite.com'])
    ->setTo(['feedback@yoursite.com'])
    ->setBody("test");

$app['mailer']->send($message);

return new Response('Thank you for your feedback!', 201);
```

Everything is done according to documentation BUT, here is an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Swift_Message::newInstance() in D:\OSPanel\domains\*************\routes\routes.php:94 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: {closure}(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) #1 D:\OSPanel\domains\*************\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php(153): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array) #2 D:\OSPanel\domains\*************\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1) #3 D:\OSPanel\domains\*************\vendor\silex\silex\src\Silex\Application.php(496): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #4 D:\OSPanel\domains\*************\vendor\silex\silex\src\Silex\Application.php(477): Silex\Application->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) #5 D:\OSPanel\domains\*************\web\index.php(5): Silex\Application->run() #6 {main} thrown in D:\OSPanel\domains\*************\routes\routes.php on line 94
```

Don't know where i'm wrong!?

Comment: Which version of swiftmailer are you using? I'm guessing you are using 6.x branch but Silex works on 5.x. Can you check on your composer.json which version of swiftmailer is installed?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I've used  a 6.x version of Swiftmailer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [mtorres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1013219/mtorres) for tip.
Silex 2 use only Swiftmailer 5.x